# Assign an order to a customer service rep in VirtoCommerce

Tags: virtocommerce, avalara

I'd like to assign each order to a customer service rep (CSR). That CSR will then be responsible to confirm any payment details, oversee shipment and answer any questions from the customer. Questions:

- How do I do that in VirtoCommerce?
- Is there a way to do that automatically?
- Is there a way for CSR to see orders assigned just to
  him personally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CustomerOrder** domain model has a properties **EmployeeId** and **EmployeeName** you may use it to store information about order responsible.

VC expose multiple extension points and one of  them is  a Events http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Extending+using+events. In you custom module you should subscribe to OrderChange event

```
        //Subscribe to cart changes. Register in avalara  SalesInvoice transaction 
        _container.RegisterType<IObserver<OrderChangeEvent>, OrderTaxAdjustmentObserver>("PlacedOrderObserver");
```

And inside you event handler implement order responsible assignment logic.

> To implement auto-assignment functionality you should create new
>   module (any of VС extension should be only in custom modules to
>   preventing merging hell on updates)

Concerning to **assigned to** UI and filtration we added  issue in github https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform/issues/559 because it is the overall order functionality and it should included in Order.Module and should be realized our team.

Comment: Cheers, that's a great answer and I appreciate putting the necessary UI updates on the product backlog. Hope you can introduce it soon!